# How do I call an Elixir function from a Phoenix LiveView heex template passing arguments with data from socket assigns?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm trying to make use of the code in this blog post: [[Phoenix LiveView] formatting date/time with local time zone](https://dev.to/mnishiguchi/phoenix-liveview-formatting-date-time-with-local-time-zone-49c).

I confirmed (with `IO.inspect`) that his `mount` and `defp` code I added to a LiveView adds the socket assigns. But he doesn't give an example of how to call the `format_time` function from a heex template. Perhaps it should be obvious, but it's not obvious to me. I tried this:

```
          <%= if connected?(@socket) do
                Cldr.format_time(@auction.started_or_paused_at,
                                 locale: @socket.assigns.locale,
                                 timezone: @socket.assigns.timezone)
              else
                Cldr.format_time(@auction.started_or_paused_at)
              end
          %>
```

But I get this error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.655.0> terminating
** (KeyError) key :locale not found in: #Phoenix.LiveView.Socket.AssignsNotInSocket<>
    (ssauction_live 0.1.0) lib/ssauction_live_web/live/auction_live/show.html.heex:32: anonymous fn/2 in SSAuctionWeb.AuctionLive.Show.render/1
...
```

I guess I can't use the [socket assigns while rendering](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/0.11.0/Phoenix.LiveView.Socket.AssignsNotInSocket.html)?

Comment: assigns inside of template are accessed via @ operator, not by socket.assigns .

Comment: Thank you [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8103819/daniel). If you submit an answer explaining that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The socket assigns are available directly inside the template as LiveEEx assigns, such as `@foo` and `@bar`. Any assign access should be done using the assigns in the template where proper change tracking takes place.

Here are the official docs: [Phoenix.LiveView.Socket.AssignsNotInSocketView](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/0.12.1/Phoenix.LiveView.Socket.AssignsNotInSocket.html)